# pandas dataframe column value update taking lot of memory

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, large-data

I have data as below in a dataframe

| FID | SID_START | SID_END |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 404915 | 1 | 3 |

and this should be expanded as below

| FID | SID |
| --- | --- |
| 404915 | 1 |
| 404915 | 2 |
| 404915 | 3 |

I am using the below code as suggested by one of the user

```
# calculate diff between end and start
n = df['SID_END'] - df['SID_START'] + 1

# repeat the index n times
df1 = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(n))

# Use cumcount to create sequential counter per group
# then add this with SID_START to calculate the SID
df1['SID'] = df['SID_START'] + df1.groupby(df1.index).cumcount()
```

Above line is consuming lot of memory (around 155 GB )and I tried the below statement as well

`df1['SID_START'] = df['SID_START'] + df1.groupby(df1.index).cumcount()`

The whole above operations happen inside a loop where I read chunks in a size of 100K and have around a 1 Billion rows , DB size is around 25GB

is there a less memory consuming way to handle this column value update ?

I have tried downgrading the datatype to int32 as well
`df1['SID_START'] = (df['SID_START'] + df1.groupby(df1.index).cumcount()).astype(numpy.int32)`

Comment: Honestly it depends on your other columns. Can you provide the output of `df.info()` of your 100k first lines, please? I think you should convert other columns as `category`.

Comment: The issue is likely not the method, but rather the data that is already quite large. Also, if your have a large `n` this will create many rows. What is the output of `n.sum()`?